# CE error on in Memory log

Tags: linux, logging, memory, hp, kernel

I Have HP server (DL360-G7) and on it run Centos7 + cPanel.
in /var/log/message I see this error:

```
EDAC MC0: 5450 CE error on CPU#0Channel#1_DIMM#0 (channel:1 slot:0
```

I change RAMs and memory slots in server but error exist yet:

```
EDAC MC0: 25509 CE error on CPU#0Channel#0_DIMM#0 (channel:0 slot:0
```

when i run this command :

```
grep "[0-9]" /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc*/csrow*/ch*_ce_count
```

I see this output:

> /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/csrow0/ch0_ce_count:5067071
>
> /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc1/csrow0/ch0_ce_count:0

In ILO panel dost have any error!

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From above logs we can say error are correctable errors, from (channel:1 slot:0 and channel:0 slot:0) mean 2 channel have issues(correctable issues). Channel is a memory controller channel, responsible to communicate with a group of DIMMs. Each channel has its own independent control (command) and data bus, and can be used independently or grouped with other channels. Check this page https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/edac.html?highlight=edac#main-concepts-used-at-the-edac-subsystem. If count is too high better is replace the DIMM and the check the motherboard for hardware errors, sometime issue is not with DIMM may be with board itself. You can ignore low count of CE errors.